# How to I add new records to a batch after it has been created?

Tags: batches

How do I add new records to a batch after it has been created in batch data entry.

Answer (score 1):

From Contributions > Batch Data Entry. Select Edit next to the batch you have created, from here you can edit the number of items which will give you new records to add to the batch you've already created.